Devexpress grid how to add a custom button with parameters
I have a Devexpress grid in ASP.NET Core. It's working fine, but I need to add a custom button to redirect to another action with the selected id.
I tried this:
columns.AddFor(m => m.Remark).Visible(false).Caption("ملاحظات").Alignment(HorizontalAlignment.Right);

columns.AddFor(m => m.AddDate).Caption("تاريخ الاضافة").Alignment(HorizontalAlignment.Right);

columns.AddFor(m => m.SanadNumber).Caption("رقم السند").Alignment(HorizontalAlignment.Right);

columns.AddFor(m => m.FullName).Caption("بواسطة").Alignment(HorizontalAlignment.Right);

columns.Add()
    .Type(GridCommandColumnType.Buttons)
    .Buttons(b =>
    {
        b.Add()
        .Icon("add")
        .OnClick(@<text>ButtonClick()</text>);
        
    });

Now I need this function ButtonClick to pass a parameter ID to the function.
<script>
     function attachButtonClick(ID) 
     {
         window.location.replace(/MYview/ID)
     };
</script>


I found a sample here, which showing us the click-handler function, I'm afraid the selected id you mentioned can be got from e.row.data if it's within the row, or we can use js selector to get that id based on the e.row.rowIndex, rowIndex shall help up locate the position.
columns.Add()
            .Type(GridCommandColumnType.Buttons)
            .Width(110)
            .Buttons(b => {
                b.Add().Name(GridColumnButtonName.Edit);
                b.Add().Name(GridColumnButtonName.Delete);

                b.Add()
                    .Hint("Clone")
                    .Icon("copy")
                    .Visible(new JS("isCloneIconVisible"))
                    .Disabled(new JS("isCloneIconDisabled"))
                    .OnClick("onCloneIconClick");
            });

function onCloneIconClick(e) {
        var clonedItem = $.extend({}, e.row.data, { ID: ++maxID });

        employees.splice(e.row.rowIndex, 0, clonedItem);
        e.component.refresh(true);
        e.event.preventDefault();
    }


Thank you very much. This answer was very useful and works well with some simple modifications
